# File specified in manifest.json could not be found on Chrome OS, Linux, MacOS/OSX, but works on Windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that runs fine on the Windows version of Chrome. When attempting to install on ChromeBox it says it can not find a PNG icon I have specified. I've tried a few icons with no luck, if I remove all the icons it defaults the icon and runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome extensions on windows are NOT case sensitive, on ChromeOS they are case sensitive.  I had icon.png specified in my manifest.js and the actual file name was Icon.png .